# Functions get called more and more times with reopening plugin

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgis

I have a QGIS plugin written in Python 2.7.3 with PyQt 4.9.1, Qt 4.8.1. When I run this plugin every function works just fine. But when I close the window and reopen it again, every function happens twice. Then I close/open again and it goes 3 times, etc., etc.

Where should I look for an error here? My `def run(self)` part looks just like this:

```
def run(self):

    self.dlg.show()

    self.availableLayers()

    self.dlg.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

    self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.groupBy)

    self.dlg.toolButton_4.clicked.connect(self.toggleRightPanel)
```

If I reload the plugin by clicking the button from "Plugin Builder", it starts again from one.

I should also mention I wouldn't like to lose the view user created (the plugin is a table viewer), but rather be able to close the window, open it and have it again there without the cells being cleared.

Comment: You probably `connect` every time u call `run`. You can fix. You can fix this by passing in `Qt.UniqueConnection` to `connect` like: `self.dlg.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openFile, Qt.UniqueConnection)`. This seems to be rather a bad design and you should probably connect your signals and slots somewhere else, but one can't help with the code you provided.

Comment: The self.availableLayers gets called every time and it should, but I thought the rest of the functions are executed only when pressing the pushButtons? Isn't it how clicked.connect works?

Comment: @adamczi. Well, you already seem to have confirmed for yourself that that is *not* how it works. Every time you call `connect`, it adds another connection - simple as that. Clearly, you need to make the connections *once* in the setup method for the dialog, not in the `run` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, moving these function calls to the setup method helped. If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `connect`, it adds another connection - even if it's to the same slot. So you need to move the connections out of the `run()` method and put them in the setup method for the dialog, so that they are only made once.

Comment: Thanks! I must have misunderstood the `connect`.